# msbuild Microsoft.NET.Sdk: how to override globbing?

Tags: c#, msbuild

It looks like the .csproj file globs all **/*.cs from the project file: I'd like instead to specify a particular subdirectory, but can't figure out the syntax, or what property to override?

How can I specify a particular subdirectory, and better yet how can I figure this out myself in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in the solution explorer, you can right click on a cs file and select **Exclude From Project** so you can exclude what you don't want.

Or you can edit the csproj file and add lines

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="FileName.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Check out [MSBuild Project File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2019) docs for more details

Comment: Thank you!  I was using <CSFile> instead of <Compile> and that seems to've fixed it.